# Repeated or conditional evaluation to solving which values of n insertion sort beats merge sort

Tags: algorithms

I'd like to solve the questions below with repeated or conditional evaluation but I don't know how.

1. Suppose we are comparing implementations of insertion sort and merge sort on the same machine. For inputs of size n, insertion sort runs in $8n^2$ steps, while merge sort runs in $64n*log(2,n)$ steps. For which values of $n$ does insertion sort beat merge sort?
2. What is the smallest value of $n$ such that an algorithm whose running time is $100n^2$ runs faster than an algorithm whose running time is $2^n$ on the same machine?

Any pseudocode would help me so much. Thank you.

Comment: This seems to be a basic math question, disguised as time complexity analysis, or perhaps an elementary programming question.

Comment: Is the analytical solution really that simple? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666503/solve-for-n-8log2-n?noredirect=1#comment5513299_2666503

Answer (score 1):

$$8n^2<64n\lg n\iff \frac n{\lg n}<64.$$

Using a grapher, $n\le588$.

---

$$100n^2<2n\iff n<\frac1{50}$$

There is no solution.

Comment: I already knew the answer, I am looking now for the mathematical process to reach the answer. The computational one I just fully described below.

Comment: The answer comes from this math department at this university: http://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~ajl213/CLRS/Ch1.pdf (Exercises 1.2.2 and 1.2.3)

Comment: This *is* the mathematical approach. Using a program is just empirism. By the way, both your answers are wrong.

Comment: @KevinLiu Honestly, this is ridiculous. You come here asking us to do your homework for you, somebody (IMO misguidedly) does so and you respond with a bunch of demands. Who on earth do you think you are?

Comment: Daoust's answer is incorrect, as it applies to $2n$, and not $2^n$. 

As to my ancestry, feel free to visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liu, but I believe that is off-topic.

Comment: @KevinLiu: I hope we can attribute your arrogance to young age...

Comment: I appreciate your observation on $2^n$

Comment: ... however, you should delete your answer because the problem doesn't contain $2n$. Again, my bad.

Comment: It appears the analytical solution to this problem is the Lambert W function, as mentioned by Joffan https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666503/solve-for-n-8log2-n?noredirect=1#comment5513299_2666503. That is what I meant by mathematical, again my mistake. The solution I posted here is the numerical one.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Whatever we think about Kevin Liu's work ethics, there's still no reason to become insulting. Please be nice. If the other party is not, disengage.